# Configure DCOM Settings with native .NET?

Tags: .net, custom-action, dcom

Some time ago I found aout about the System.Directory namespace in .NET 3.5 that enables me to basically manage local as well as domain accounts easily with native .NET methods instead of using API calls and importing unmanaged DLLs.

Now I need to configure DCOM settings for some legacy application from within an MSI setup. As far as I know there is no way doing it with on board means of InstallShield 2009.

Is there any way of configuring DCOM settings with .NET so that I would be able to write a managed Custom Action e.g.?

Answer (score 0):

Not in .NET, as far as I know. See [dcomcnfg functionality programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454368/dcomcnfg-functionality-programmatically#455903)